# Mounting Windows HDD from an OpenSolaris LiveCD

Tags: windows, solaris, mount, opensolaris

I´m running openSolaris LiveCD on a computer that runs Windows XP.

How can I mount the 2 partitions I have in Windows, and be able to access them from the Solaris?

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I would spend my time burning any number of Linux LiveCDs than to try to get fuse and ntfs-3g working on an OpenSolaris LiveCD.  I think it's possible though, good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

If your XP partitions are FAT based, you can directly mount them as pcfs is natively supported by the OS.
Use something like
"mount -F pcfs /dev/dsk/c0t0d0p1 /mnt" assuming you want to mount the first partiton of your the disck connected to controller 0 (you need to first figure out what your disk device is).

If your partition is NTFS based, there are already packaged solutions like ASntfs-3g-2009.4.4 on sunfreepacks.com. However, I doubt they would be installable on a live distribution which is definitely read-only.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a live CD then each time you can install FSWfsmisc package from the net and then mount with "-F ntfs". Details [here](http://aminsblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/mount-ntfs-in-solaris-11/).